# (pyQt/pySide)setStyleSheet(border....) makes QPushButton not clickable in Maya

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, maya

guys. 
Trying to learn PyQt inside Maya and I am facing little problem which is more of discomfort then a problem. When I set border for my button :

```
button.setStyleSheet('
 background-color: rgb(120, 120, 100);
 color:rgb(1, 255, 255);
 border: none')
```

My button is still working , but visually it's not clickable , if you click on button it's being static.  Anybody faced that problem and knows how to solve ? Any help will really appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is in `border: none`, since there is no border, it can not move it, so it does not give the visual sensation of the pressed button, remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the **Qt Style Sheet** documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#pseudo-states).

You can use the **pseudo-states** hover, checked, pressed, to change the look and feel of your button under these circumnstances.

As an example, you can make the background darker when the button is pressed with:

```
QPushButton:pressed { background-color: rgb(80, 80, 60); }
```

Otherwise, your button will always look the same no matter if it is pressed or not.

Comment: Thanks it's quite helpful!